# Differential Geometry - Leading Terms

Tags: differential-geometry, harmonic-functions

Recall in class we have shown that, for any surface $M$ with first fundamental form $I = g_{ij} dv^i dv^j$,  the Laplace operator $\Delta_M$ is given by

$\Delta_Mf\ =\ $$\sum_{i,j} f_{v^iv^j}g^{ij}$ + first order derivatives of $f$

$I\ =\ \{1+[ϕ'(u)]^2\}du^2+2aϕ'(u)dudv+(u^2+a^2)dv^2$

Find the leading term $\sum_{i,j} g^{ij}f_{v^iv^j}$ of $\Delta_Mf$

This question is an extra credit question for my class. No idea how to go about it though. More interested in learning how to do the problem rather than the extra credit.

Comment: You're given $g_{ij}$, and the only information you're missing appears to be $g^{ij}$. So presumably you only need to invert the metric and find $g^{ij}$, then you can plug the coefficients into the sum.

Comment: would you mind showing me please? this question covers a topic we haven't discussed in full detail

Comment: You're asking us to explicitly solve a question for *you* to get extra credit for your class?

Comment: the due date for the assignment is already over and my teacher didn't post any solutions for the question, it wouldn't benefit me in any way other than just learning how to do the problem